# Display popup on start of activity

Tags: android, android-activity, popup

I need to display a popup as soon as an activity has started, however I end up with the application crashing, my current code:

```
public class GameActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    Button firstAnswer;
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        ...
        firstAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.firstanswerbtn);
        ...
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()

        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.playpopup, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Button play = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.letsplay);
        play.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playRound();
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });

        popupWindow.showAtLocation(firstAnswer, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }

    ...
}
```

However I end up with a crash:

```
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jabu.com.languagetemplate/jabu.com.languagetemplate.GameActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:562)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1058)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:887)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:851)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at package.GameActivity.onStart(GameActivity.java:142)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-02 22:27:27.534: E/AndroidRuntime(28142):    ... 10 more
```

Line 142 is:

```
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(firstAnswer, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
firstAnswer.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     pw.showAtLocation(firstAnswer, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
   }
});
```

Even if you set your main layout in the onCreate method it's not enough. You need to queue this operation until everything is ready.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or - simply launch your popup window from onResume().

Comment: If you call the show method from within the onResume the exception occurs anyway.